# Build Error in Android Studio "Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'"

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt

i am building a notes app in android studio. I am new to it so i am following a tutorial but this error pops up everytime i try to build my project. What could be the solution to this.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
```

###### Below is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.studentapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.studentapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    //Navigation Components
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'

    //Room Database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0"


    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1'

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30"

    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
}
```

###### And the project gradle file is below

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript{
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete)    {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have searched the whole web for this but there seems to be no solution. The error says to use toolchain, and i tried but that didnt help or maybe i implemented it wrong.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this error?